# Root decomposition of lie algebra from the decomposition of the complexification

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Currently I'm reading *Representations of Compact Lie Groups* (Brocker) and in *V-2.1* Brocker writes a decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g_\mathbb{C}}$ by the weight spaces. The book marks:

$$L_\chi = \{v\in \mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C}\mid \forall_{h\in{\mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C}}} [h,v]= \chi(h)\cdot v \}$$

Where $\chi$ is some complex root of the torus (lie algebra). Then the book says that we can decompose:

$$ \mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C} = L_0 \oplus \bigoplus_{\chi \in R} L_\chi$$

where $R$ is all of the real roots of $\mathfrak{t}$. Now my first question is why is this decomposition even true? I would understand if $R$ is the set of complex roots (then it's just the regular weight space decomposition) but that's not the case here. Is there a mistake in the book?

My second question involves the second part shown in the book. Here we define: $M_\chi = (L_\chi \oplus L_{-\chi}) \cap \mathfrak{g}$ and than the book claims (without proof) that:

$$\mathfrak{g} = M_0 \oplus \bigoplus_{\chi \in R^+} M_\chi$$

where $R^+$ is a set containing exactly one copy from each pair of real roots $\{\chi, -\chi\}$. Why is this decomposition true?

If I assume that in the decomposition $L_\chi$ is the weight space of the complex root that matches the real root $\chi$, than I was able to show that:

$$ V(\chi) \otimes \mathbb{C} = L_\chi $$

where $V(\chi)$ is the weight space of the real root. Here I got stuck.

Comment: I admit, I'm somewhat confused by their wording also. I believe they must mean that $L_\alpha$ is the root space with root the corresponding complex root (or at least the corresponding "infinitesimal" root in their terminology). So then it is just the standard root decomposition albeit we are probably thinking of the complexification as a real Lie algebra so all the root spaces have dimension 2 and so on

Comment: What exactly is the definition of $\mathfrak t$ and "the real roots of $\mathfrak t$" in this context (I do not have the book at hand right now)?